# cookie returning null but not in fiddle

Tags: javascript

I am pasting the fiddle js code and returning null. But on fiddle the result is 5. Why is it not returning correctly?

https://jsfiddle.net/ay7xnzvz/

```
 document.cookie = "test=5";
 function read_cookie(k,r){return(r=RegExp('(^|; )'+encodeURIComponent(k)+'=    ([^;]*)').exec(document.cookie))?r[2]:null;}

var x = read_cookie("test", document.cookie);
alert(x);
```

Comment: what are you expecting to get ?

Comment: i am expecting to get the number five as the output. its working in the fiddle but i am getting null when i paste that in.

Comment: maybe i forgot an import for this if there is one?

Comment: where did you paste it ? you need to show us your full code

Comment: i am just pasting it in a script. <html> <script> code here </script> </html> alert is null

Comment: can you try pasting it and see what you return?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are not runing this script in a web server, you are just opening the `file.html` ( wich containe that script ) localy.

To work with cookie you need a web server.

> When receiving an HTTP request, a server can send a Set-Cookie header
>   with the response. Afterward, the cookie value is sent along with
>   every request made to the same server in the form of a Cookie HTTP
>   header. Additionally, an expiration delay can be specified.
>   Restrictions to a specific domain and path can be specified as well. - Via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox console your code is returning `null`.

However in Chrome it is returning `5`.

To make it return same value in both browsers and in jsfidle:

```
var c1= document.cookie = "test=5";
function read_cookie(k,r){return(r=RegExp('(^|; )'+encodeURIComponent(k)+'=([^;]*)').exec(c1))?r[2]:null;}

var x = read_cookie("test", c1);
alert(x);
```